# Transmitting video stream from device on local machine to Signal running on ssh server

Tags: ssh, video

(Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/can-i-pipe-dev-video-over-ssh, [Webcam works as root but not as normal user: what permissions do I need to change?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471009/webcam-works-as-root-but-not-as-normal-user-what-permissions-do-i-need-to-chang))

I have a setup in which there is a webcam (on /dev/video0) on my local machine (machine A), and I'm using a ssh client on machine A to connect to a ssh server on machine B, and run Signal on machine B for a attempted video call, with X11 forwarding over the ssh connection so that the Signal window appears back on the screen of machine A.  (As it happens, machine B is not a real machine, it's a Docker container hosted on machine A.)  Is it possible to get the video stream to Signal for use in the video call, and if so, how, please?

Comment: For now, I'm working around this with the --device=/dev/video0 option to docker run, but I'd prefer a solution that tunnels the video stream over the ssh connection if possible.